# RDF Post Office Box modeling

Tags: rdf

Hi
I have Addresses information that include P.O Box number , how can I model RDF/XML representation for this P.O Box , is there any VCARD properties for this ??

I will appreciate any examples

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, have a look at ...

[Representing vCard Objects in RDF](http://www.w3.org/Submission/vcard-rdf/)

You'll find pretty much all what you need in there. The document is full of examples to follow step by step. There are some more examples in [RDF vCard Examples](http://www.slis.kent.edu/~mzeng/metadata/schemas/vcard.htm)

**Edit to clarify on the PO Box predicate**

To represent PO Box information if you see the ontology you have the following `ObjectProperty`:

```
<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#post-office-box">
   <rdfs:label>P.O. Box</rdfs:label>
   <rdfs:comment>The post office box of a postal address</rdfs:comment>
   <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#Address"/>
</owl:DatatypeProperty>
```

Since the domain is Address, any subject were this predicate is applied will be considered an Address. An example:

```
<v:adr>
  <rdf:Description>
    <v:post-office-box>YOUR PO BOX CODE</v:post-office-box>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#Address"/>
  </rdf:Description>  
</v:adr>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and link.
I saw that before , but I did not find suitable vcard to represent P.O.Box
for example here is my rdf: 

`<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.abc.com">
 <v:title>Title</v:fn>
 <v:locality>locality</v:locality>
 <v:postal-code>92272</v:postal-code>
 <v:tel>0000000</v:tel>
 <v:fax>000000</v:fax>
 //the P.O.Box should be here 
 <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Agent" />
</rdf:Description>
`


I want to add P.O.Box attribure to that 
how can I make it , the link you provide has no info about the P.O.Box

Comment: Search in the document `Representing vCard Objects in RDF` for `post-office-box` and you'll see the predicate `http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#post-office-box` so just use `v:post-office-box`. See also the new edition of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use RDF  VCARD  ADR property.

```
 ADR            Post Office Box        Pobox
                Extended Address       Extadd
                Street Address         Street
                Locality               Locality
                Region                 Region
                Postal Code            Pcode
                Country                Country
```

here you can use Pobox